# Uniqueness of QR factorization

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

If Matrix A is square and non-singular and there exists a QR factorization A=QR where Q is unitary and R is upper triangular. How can I prove that QR factorization is unique when rjj > 0 for all J

Comment: As a warm up problem, you could try showing that the first column of $Q$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: Is it unique irrespective of the algorithm used?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what algorithm is used. Let $q_1$ be the first column of $Q$. What is the first column of $QR$?

Comment: The first column of QR will be q1*r11. That is the first column of A

Comment: If i take 2 QR factorizations, Q1R1 and Q2R2 and calculate (A^T) A (A transpose*A), then I get 2 equal diagonal matrices of (R1)^T.R1 and (R2)^T. R2. How can I prove that both the R's are same

Comment: Let $a_1$ be the first column of $A$. As you mentioned, $a_1 = q_1 r_{11}$. We also know that $q_1$ is a unit vector and $r_{11} > 0$. How many different ways are there to take a vector $a_1$ and write it as a unit vector scaled by a positive number?

Comment: I think there is only one way. By normalizing the vector and by dividing the original vector with the normalized vector.

Comment: I don't understand why rjj has to be greater than 0 for QR to be unique. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: If $r_{11}$ is not restricted to be positive, how many ways are there to write $a_1$ as $a_1 = q_1 r_{11}$, where $q_1$ is a unit vector?

Comment: There are 2 ways, a1= q1. r11 and   
 a1= (-q1).(-r11)

Comment: @yes exactly. So if $r_{11}$ is restricted to be positive then there is only one possible choice for the first column of $Q$.